# Tabbed Split View for iPad (switch detail views)

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ipad

Ultimately, here is what I want to do:

Left sidebar of Navigation Tabs
Right Detail view

I know how to set properties of controls in the right detail view based off of the selected tab on the left. But that doesn't work for what I'm doing.

For example, assume I'm referring to the Settings app in the iPad. When you click on one of the tabs on the left, the right side loads in a completely different set of controls (labels, buttons, etc). This is what I'm looking for.

Any ideas or examples to go about starting something like this?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking can be found in a framework called ChocolateChip UI. Here's the link:

http://chocolatechip-ui.com/